# Using jQuery, how to find the index of an element amongst its siblings of a specified CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="component">
    <div class="component">
        <div class="component">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="component">
        <div class="somethingelse">
        </div>
        <div class="component">
        </div>
        <div class="component">
            <input type="button" value="Get Path" onclick="showPath(this)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write the function `showPath` so that it returns the index of the parent `div` in relation to its siblings of class `component`.  So in the above sample, I would like the function to return `1`.

I've got this far, but it returns `2`; I don't know what to do to ignore the `div` of class `somethingelse`

```
function showPath(element) {
    var component = $(element).closest('.component');
    alert(component.index());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this(haven't tested):

```
function showPath(element) {      
  var component = $(element).closest('.component');     
  alert(component.parent().find(".component").index(component)); 
}
```

Comment: I think you want `.children(".component")`, as `.find()` will return all descendants at any level.

Answer (score 9):

A quick and simple extension for jQ to turn this process into a method:

```
$.fn.getIndex = function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().children().index( $(this) );
    return index;
}
```

Run this on document.ready or wrap it in a function and run it that way (probably cleaner).

Usage is as simple as

```
var index_for_element = $('.thing-you-want-index-for').getIndex();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this.

```
$('input').click(function() {
    var component = $(this).closest('.component');
    alert(component.parent().children(".component").index(component));
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Qzk6A/2/